# How to set up an alert for secret expiry for service principal?

Tags: azure, secret-key, azure-service-principal

In Azure, We are having service principal for client apps in Azure. We want to set up an alert to our group, some days before the expiry of the secret. So that we can generate new ones and update our apps without downtime. Is there any way to get an alert? If not how to manage these?

Comment: Any details on what you have tried?

Comment: I thought we can set an alert directly, but I didn't find any option in the Azure portal. I feel it will be the same for all who use the service principal. So thought of understanding others if any approach is already there that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [Graph Api](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to get a list of applications withs secrets that are about to expire. If you combine this with a [Timer Triggered Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) you can create an alert and/or create a new secret automatically.

I've created an Azure Function that can act as a source of inspiration, see [this repo](https://github.com/Brink-Software/Aad-secret-and-certificate-expiration-notification). It contains a class that lists all secrets and certificates that are about to expire

```cs
    public class GraphApiReader : IGraphApiReader
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly Func<PasswordCredential, bool> _expiringSecretsSelector;
        private readonly Func<KeyCredential, bool> _expiringCertificatesSelector;

        public GraphApiReader(
            IOptions<GraphServiceCredentials> graphServiceConfiguration,
            IOptions<NotificationConfiguration> notificationConfiguration)
        {
            if (graphServiceConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphServiceConfiguration));
            if (notificationConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(notificationConfiguration));

            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(graphServiceConfiguration.Value.AppId)
                .WithTenantId(graphServiceConfiguration.Value.TenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(graphServiceConfiguration.Value.ClientSecret)
                .Build();
            var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            _expiringSecretsSelector = new Func<PasswordCredential, bool>(c =>
                c.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(notificationConfiguration.Value.ExpirationThresholdInDays));

            _expiringCertificatesSelector = new Func<KeyCredential, bool>(c =>
                c.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(notificationConfiguration.Value.ExpirationThresholdInDays));
        }

        public async Task<List<Subject>> ReadExpiringSubjectsAsync()
        {
            var subjects = new List<Subject>();

            var initialApplicationsCollectionPage = await _graphServiceClient.Applications
                .Request()
                .Select(app => new
                {
                    app.KeyCredentials,
                    app.AppId,
                    app.CreatedDateTime,
                    app.DisplayName,
                    app.PasswordCredentials
                })
                .GetAsync();

            var iterator = PageIterator<Application>.CreatePageIterator(_graphServiceClient, initialApplicationsCollectionPage, application =>
            {
                if (!application.PasswordCredentials.Any(_expiringSecretsSelector) &&
                    !application.KeyCredentials.Any(_expiringCertificatesSelector))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                var appRegistration = new AppRegistration
                {
                    AppId = application.AppId,
                    DisplayName = application.DisplayName,
                    CreatedDateTime = application.CreatedDateTime
                };

                subjects.AddRange(application.PasswordCredentials.Where(_expiringSecretsSelector).Select(cred => new Subject
                {
                    DisplayName = cred.DisplayName,
                    Context = cred.Hint,
                    EndDateTime = cred.EndDateTime,
                    StartDateTime = cred.StartDateTime,
                    Id = cred.KeyId.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(),
                    ODataType = cred.ODataType,
                    AppRegistration = appRegistration
                }));

                subjects.AddRange(application.KeyCredentials.Where(_expiringCertificatesSelector).Select(key => new Subject
                {
                    DisplayName = key.DisplayName,
                    Context = Convert.ToBase64String(key.CustomKeyIdentifier),
                    EndDateTime = key.EndDateTime,
                    StartDateTime = key.StartDateTime,
                    Id = key.KeyId.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(),
                    ODataType = key.ODataType,
                    AppRegistration = appRegistration
                }));

                return true;
            });

            await iterator.IterateAsync();

            return subjects;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to set up an alert for secret expiry for service principal? If not how to manage these?

AFAIK, There is no way you can get an alert about Secret Expiry for Service Principal.
But if you want to know about the expiry dates of Secrets then you can follow below process:

- Firstly, go to azure active directory service in Azure Portal
- Then Click on App Registrations, Then Click on Your App

Then follow below process:

[image]

You can manually check which service expires by following above process.

Another way of managing these are when creating these Secrets you will have something called Expires as below:

[image]

So if we keep maximum 2 yrs then it will expire after 2 yrs of creation. If you keep 90 days it will expire after 90 days.

You can [monitor](https://community.dynamics.com/business/b/that-nav-guy/posts/azure-using-logic-apps-to-monitor-azure-app-registration-expiration) the expiry using Logic Apps too.

Comment: ok, So Azure doesn't have any default easy way of configuring alerts to notify the expiry.